# Cosa significa 'vecchio guercio'

Tags: word-meaning

[Guercio](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/G/guercio.shtml), come i principali dizionari indicano, ha più di un significato:

> - Affetto da strabismo; per estens., che è cieco da un occhio o ha la vista difettosa.

L'espessione più usata è di solito *un vecchio guercio*. Ma a quale significato di guercio si riferisce? È cosigliabile usare altri aggettivi per evitare malintesi?

Comment: Nella mia esperienza, significa quasi sempre "cieco da un occhio" (o perlomeno è quello che io penso quando sento o leggo la parola). Poi naturalmente si può anche usare per esagerare, ossia per riferirsi a qualcuno che non è realmente cieco ma ci vede molto male, o semplicemente per ironizzare. In quei casi il contesto chiarisce (o dovrebbe chiarire).

Comment: Si, la cosa strana secondo me e' che essere strabico, cieco da un occhio o vederci male sono tutti  difetti o  handicap visivi ma molto diversi tra di loro.

Comment: Effettivamente nel caso del "vecchio guercio" potrebbe anche significare semplicemente "che ci vede poco", senza contesto è difficile dirlo esattamente.